# Javascript and meteor full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, fullcalendar

I seem to be having trouble with full calendars first day option. I am using meteor version 0.8.3 and the full calendar 2.0 package from https://github.com/J-Katzen/meteor-fullcalendar2.git

This is my code

```
$('#sellers-viewings-calendar').fullCalendar({
    firstDay:1,
    defaultView: "agendaWeek",
    minTime: "08:00:00",
    maxTime: "20:00:00",
});
```

The first line as the documentation suggests sets the first day to a monday. The calendar still renders starting on a Sunday. I ultimately would like to set this to the following function so we always have the 7 days in the future in view

```
function dayNumber() {
    var day = moment(new Date()).format('dddd');
    if (day === 'Sunday') { return 0; }
    else if (day === 'Monday') { return 1; }
    else if (day === 'Tuesday') { return 2; }
    else if (day === 'Wednesday') { return 3; }
    else if (day === 'Thursday') { return 4; }
    else if (day === 'Friday') { return 5; }
    else if (day === 'Saturday') { return 6; }
    else { return 1; }
}
```

Any ideas on refactoring the function are welcome :)

Thanks!

Comment: I have sorted the function ==== function dayNumber() {
      return new Date().getDay();
  }

Comment: Maybe [FullCalendarTest repo](https://github.com/parhelium/testFullCalendar) would be helpful for you